# Renamed Android Project file and now everything isn't working

Tags: android, eclipse

So I wanted to rename the folder that my Android file was in because it didn't match what I wanted it to be. So I renamed it on my desktop and now everything is messed up. It split up 2 files, one with the original name with nothing in it but the files and the one i renamed it to.

[image]

I am honestly stressing out so hard and I am not sure what to do.

Comment: you need to refractor for renaming any folder.

Comment: @RandykaYudhistira Yeah, I learned that one the hard was sadly.

Comment: Use Alt+Shift+R or Right click project -> Refactor -> Rename

Comment: @HarshaVardhan I get it... That's not what I am asking.

Comment: Can you explain the problem properly,  Post is not so clear

Comment: @HarshaVardhan Sorry if my comment came off as rude. So I had a working android project. The file for this was on my desktop. (Like an idiot) I renamed the folder on my desktop using Finder and when I came back to my eclipse project it looked like how the picture is above.

Comment: Since, you have renamed project in desktop folder, the package names are not updated properly in all the java class. So, You can replace again in desktop and come to eclipse and rename properly or Search the package name which is error and then replace all with proper package name

Comment: @HarshaVardhan but why did it mess with everything in my workplace folder as pictured above? how do I get it all back to normal?

Comment: @Lewis, If code is in any repository just rollback. Or I have add comment with 2 approaches, you can follow any of one. If you change any structure in desktop, it directly links to the project structure of eclipse.

Comment: @HarshaVardhan I never used a repository.

Comment: @Lewis Can you add information about what was project name before and what you renamed? This may help to get answer of your question

Comment: Dont wast time in this, create new project with project and package name you want and copy related files in it.